# hive using serdeproperties gives error

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to create the hive table so that the hdfs file system have UTF-8 Format, the problem is the query is giving error, not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS output_2057565014;
CREATE TABLE temp.output_2057565014
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY 'ธ'
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '|'
MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '$'
with serdeproperties('serialization.encoding'='UTF-8') 
LOCATION '/tmp/test-2057565014' 
AS
SELECT * from temp.abc
```

Comment: i think you should use `row format serde ...` if you plan to use `serde properties`

Comment: Duh. I thought Hadoop and Hive **always** assumed UTF-8 by default; what kind of cluster setup do you use?!? _>> Reference: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-7142_

Comment: Follow-up: `serialization.encoding`is not yet supported by all SerDes, cf. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-15826 not integrated into the code base.

Answer (score 0):

*"the query is giving error"* > yeah, but what kind?? Maybe reading that error message would help. Without it, it's just guesswork.
So, let's guess.

---

`ROW FORMAT DELIMITED` clause implicitly assumes that delimiter characters are **single ASCII-7 characters**, either defined explicitly (when printable) or by their octal code.

Hence `FIELDS TERMINATED BY 'ธ'` is not valid.

You can try different workarounds -- changing the delimiter in the upstream file creation process; changing the delimiter *in situ* before loading to HDFS (e.g. with a good old `sed` command); trying a hard-coded column mapping with [RegExSerde](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-662) (cf. [Language Manual DLL / CREATE TABLE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableCreate/Drop/TruncateTable) under "Row Formats & SerDe")...