# Hive CREATE TABLE statement with SERDEPROPERTIES throws an error

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, amazon-emr, hortonworks-data-platform

I am in the midst of a migration project from HDP to AWS EMR. As part of the effort, we are creating tables in EMR Hive using the `CREATE TABLE` statements from HDP, which we get using the `show create table` command. One such `CREATE TABLE` DDL is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table(column_list)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.encoding'='ISO-8859-1')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://path/to/data'
```

As part of a process, we ran the modified statement as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table(column_list)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.encoding'='ISO-8859-1')
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION
  's3://path/to/data'
```

When we ran this, it failed with the following error:

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 28:0 missing EOF at 'WITH' near ''org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'' (state=42000,code=40000)
```

Looking it up on StackOverflow, we got this [hive using serdeproperties gives error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50280281/hive-using-serdeproperties-gives-error), and looked at the comments left for the question. We decided to remove the `WITH SERDEPROPERTIES` part, and ran it again. It didn't throw any error this time. We then did an `ALTER TABLE test_table SET SERDEPROPERTIES('serialization.encoding'='ISO-8859-1')`, which worked. Curious, we did a `show create table` on EMR and got this:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table(column_list)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'field.delim'='|',
  'line.delim'='\n',
  'serialization.encoding'='ISO-8859-1',
  'serialization.format'='|')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://path/to/data'
```

As can be seen, this is a bit different from what HDP shows us. What would be a good, minimally invasive way to get the script from HDP to run seamlessly on EMR? Also, why does the error occur? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please escape any special characters in a query. like '|' as '\|'